# Chain Rule Question.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Why do we write the derivative of

$$\frac{d}{dK_2} max_N  (A_2K_2^aN_2^{1-a}  - W_2N_2)$$

as

$$\frac{d}{dK_2} A_2K_2^aN_2^{1-a}  - W_2N_2 + \frac{d}{dN_2}\left ((A_2K_2^aN_2^{1-a}  - W_2N_2)       (\frac{dN_2}{dK_2})\right)$$

with the chain rule?

P.S the N next to max is the just $$N_2$$

Comment: Could you check  the first expression again

Comment: @user159888 sorry, edited. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: What is N in the first expression?

Comment: sorry N is just the N_2

Comment: @joriki is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ using `\max`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.